# String could not be parsed as XML php android webservice Error

Tags: php, android, xml-parsing, android-webservice

it is not passing url value from php to xml conversion

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 141:      parser error              : EntityRef: expecting ';' in /home/u395985035/public_html/ddd/ddd.php on line 34

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): http://teko.gogo.com/gtw_c?tem_id=844&erw_id=44545 in /home/u395985035/public_html/ddd/ddd.php on line 34

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in /home/u395985035/public_html/ddd/ddd.php on line 34

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could
>   not be parsed as XML' in /home/u395985035/public_html/ddd/ddd.php:34
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/u395985035/public_html/ddd/ddd.php(34):
>   SimpleXMLElement->__construct('\n\t\t

```
    <?php

  include("config.php"); 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table1";
    $q   = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $xml = "<demo1>\n\t\t";

    while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q))   {
      $xml .= "<t_view>\n\t";
      $xml .= "<l1>".$r['id']."</l1>\n\t\t";  
      $xml .= "<l2>".$r['link1']."</l2>\n\t\t";
      $xml .= "</t_view>\n\t";  
    }

       $xml .= "</demo1>\n\t\t";
    $sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
    $sxe->asXML("ddd.xml");

 /* I am parsing url link with parameters in $r['link1'] */
?>
```

Comment: can you paste code from ddd.php file causing error?

Comment: code is placed for your reference.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error , it seems there could be problem in your records , I created the same table with 'id' and 'link1' fields , inserted some dummy data and run the codes , it is working fine.

Comment: In my case its produces above error.

Comment: only simple string of url is working like "https://www.google.co.in/" but "http://teko.gogo.com/gtw_c?tem_id=844&erw_id=44545" this kind of link produce error.

Comment: ok I am able to reproduce it , please use urlencode('http://teko.gogo.com/gtw_c?tem_id=844&erw_id=44545') function before inserting link1 in database, I have tested it and it is working , let me know if have any issue.

Comment: Did this trick work for you?

Comment: no, if I use encode than how can I decode on android side?

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Okay don't encode your url just try this , I have tested and it is working.

```
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($q))   {
      $xml .= "<t_view>\n\t";
      $xml .= "<l1>".$r['id']."</l1>\n\t\t";  
      $xml .= "<l2>".preg_replace('#&(?=[a-z_0-9]+=)#', '&amp;', $r['link1'])."</l2>\n\t\t";
      $xml .= "</t_view>\n\t";  
    }
```